# Product of power series

Tags: power-series

Please how to write this series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right) z^n,\ z\in\Bbb C$$

into a product of power series?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos why i can't ask an other question ?

Comment: Perhaps that you will find the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: it is not good i ask a simple question that i don't know how to do it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right)z^n = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z^k}{k} z^{n-k} = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} z^n\right)$$

Comment: can you please explaine me from where we get this? it is always like this  ?

Comment: This is how works the product of two series : see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product